# How to call a function from another function without constructor in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function

I need to call from my function "**RegisterTaster**" to my function "**endRegisterAlert**" but actually im not using constructor because i use the class like a const in react native.

**How can i call the function ?**

```
const Validator=(props)=>{

  async function RegisterTaster(){
    //do something...
    endRegisterAlert();
  }

  function endRegisterAlert(){
   //do something
  }

 return(
    <Button onPress={async ()=> await RegisterTaster() }> 
                    <Text >Register</Text> 
    </Button
  );
 }

export default Validator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this.

```
const Validator=(props)=>{

  async function RegisterTaster(){
    //do something...
    endRegisterAlert();
  }

  function endRegisterAlert(){
   //do something
  }

 return(
    <Button onPress={RegisterTaster}> 
                    <Text >Register</Text> 
    </Button
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function-based React Component.

Everything is right except for the part that you are awaiting an async function.

Do it this way:

```
return(
  <Button onPress={RegisterTaster}> 
     <Text>Register</Text> 
  </Button
);
```

OR:

```
return(
  <Button onPress={() => RegisterTaster()}> 
     <Text>Register</Text> 
  </Button
);
```

Either way, it should work.